# Add obcject model to remote reporting services

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I create reports definition of my reports in Visual Studio by *rdlc. I connect to them with Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer and use them as ProcessingMode.Local and it was good. As a data source I used my own POCO classes.

Now I need move it to remote machine. My first problem was that I had *.rdlc and change it to *.rdl type. Ok, I changed this, changed Reporting to Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms, parameters type, insert credentials, but... I have problem with data source.
In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(vs.80).aspx they wrote, to change data source type, but I don't know how :(

I want to use my own objects (list of objects) as a data source.

edit: I can parse them to DataTable, but if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write SQL queries to retrieve the business objects from the database. SSRS does not support business objects data sources and is not a valid data source when deploying remotely.

Alternatively, if you wrote your RDLC using a DataTable as a source, it should convert automatically according to the documentation (though I have no experience with this).

Comment: You mean change List<MyObj> to DataTable in memory and pass DataTable as DataSource or... make DataTable in Database and pass my data to Database and... get data from DB??